# Suddenly file not found XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I got my project can be built yesterday, but today suddenly it cannot find my Core Data properties file:

> clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/blah/blah/projectName/Core Data/Core Data
>   Object/Buffer+CoreDataProperties.m' clang: error: no input files

File is there but XCode can't read it!

Also looking from below path, my file is extended by strange code:

Path:

> /Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectName-cymkejafdlvsqtbjfccohjatfyar/Build/Intermediates/projectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/projectName.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/

Strange code in file:

> Buffer+CoreDataProperties-4B8312AED3B74D8C.dia

Is there anyone can fix this problem?

Comment: So from the command line, typing `ls -l /Users/blah/blah/projectName/Core\ Data/Core\ Data\ Object/Buffer+CoreDataProperties.m` shows something?  That business about "extended by strange code" and the `.dia` is not relevant.

Comment: Well no. I just realized that actually the projectName folder must be twice, but XCode only refer to one folder only.

Comment: So something has changed either in the Xcode project or the filesystem?

Comment: Not sure which one, but I am sure that the XCode musn't be changed, since I can build it yesterday for a release.

Comment: Do you use `git` to track changes?

Comment: Nope unfortunately :(

Comment: Oh well if you don't *manage change* then this is what happens.  Enjoy!

Comment: Did you try removing the file reference from Xcode's project navigator, and re-adding it?

Comment: trojanfoe thanks! NicolasMiari: Yes, I usually do that, but last time I did was before the release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually it is an XCode bug I suspect!

It was caused by **wrong files reference**!

I found that there are broken files (which are those files that cause error) in Build Phases (the one without image with m letter inside), so I removed them and it works again!